# Using ESC key to dismiss modal type dialog in Google Chrome causes lack of response

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I ran into a small but frustrating issue with Google Chrome when dismissing a modal type dialog( `alert` in this instance but `prompt` exhibits the same behaviour. ) Usually one expects that the `Esc` will cancel / close things - on the web it commonly will close a popup ( such as those described ) and indeed that is the case. The problem I have witnessed revolves around the fact that once the dialog is dismissed/closed the elements on the page become unresponsive to certain actions.

[One article I read](https://www.zdnet.com/article/google-changes-how-the-escape-key-is-handled-in-chrome-to-fight-popup-ads/) seemed to offer a glimpse of what might be happening with Google continually fighting spam of one sort or another but this does not seem to fully fit the facts.

Even using `focus()` after the alert offers no solution - is this a fault in the javascript logic here, my understanding or a special feature I was not aware of? I looked over serveral of the possible `duplicates` whilst writing the question - none seemed to fit.

A very simple example below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <title>Using the `Esc` key to dismiss modal type dialogs</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name='emulator' method='post'>
            <input type='text' name='message' value='banana' />
            <input type='button' name='bttn' value='Submit' />
        </form>
        <!--
        
            Two browsers to test: Chrome & Firefox
            
            In Chrome(Version 84.0.4147.135) a bug seems to prevent normal page operation
            if the `Esc` key is pressed to dismiss the alert prompt. Clicking the button on 
            the `alert` does not yield the same error/problem however and this is not an 
            issue in FF.
            
            There IS page interaction required before the bug/undocumented feature becomes 
            apparent so it seems that the new features designed by google to fight `popup spam`
            ( https://www.zdnet.com/article/google-changes-how-the-escape-key-is-handled-in-chrome-to-fight-popup-ads/ )
            is not relevant.
            
            In Firefox using the `Esc` key no adverse effects are observed and it
            behaves as one might expect.
            
        -->
        <script>
            
            const args={ 'bubbles':true, 'cancelable':true };
            const evt=new Event('click',args);
            
            const form=document.forms.emulator;
            const bttn=form.bttn;
            const input=form.message;
            
            /* listen for keypress events and respond with custom event for `enter` key press */
            form.addEventListener('keypress',(e)=>{
                if( e.key === 'Enter' ){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    bttn.dispatchEvent(evt);
                }
            });
            
            /* display a modal type dialog in response to triggered event */
            bttn.addEventListener( 'click', (e) => alert( input.value ) );
            /*
                alternate version - same result
                bttn.addEventListener( 'click', (e) => { alert( input.value ); input.focus(); } );
            */
        </script>
        
        <h2>Process to test/duplicate:</h2>
        <ol>
            <li>Open page in Chrome and Firefox</li>
            <li>Click into the text field to give focus - add some text. ( this stage optional )</li>
            <li>Hit `Enter` on keyboard OR press `Submit` button. An alert will appear displaying the contents of the text field</li>
            <li>Hit `Esc` on keyboard to dismiss the alert. The alert will disappear.</li>
            <li>Click into the textfield again and type - in Chrome focus will not return and button will not respond. In Firefox all OK.</li>
        </ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sure looks like a bug. One workaround: switch to a different tab/window and back. Better option: do not ever use `alert` or `confirm` or `prompt`, they have a bunch of problems (I guess this bug is one of them too) use proper modals instead

Comment: I agree - switching tab and back or clicking the button seemed to return things to normal. I've not witnessed this sort of problem before but will use an alternative of some sort to the `alert` call.